# jQuery UI slider, using time as range (not timeline.js) , fixed width

Tags: jquery, timeline, jquery-ui-slider

what happens if i have more number of years than it is physically possible to include within a slider and yet make it look pretty is there any way to make a slider continuous on a fixed width ?

for eg :

width of the slider is 600 px

years need to be accommodated is 100 years (1900-2000) (each mark on the slider is one year)

However inorder to write the years on top of the marks and make it look nice i can only accommodate 30 years in 600 px..

1st screen : slider will show 1900-1930

is there any way in which i can keep moving the marks on the slider as i get to the end of the slider , i.e when the slider handle reaches 1925 the slider moves to the left and another 10 years are added to the slider marks

when i move the handle to 1925

slider will show 1910 - 1940 ...

i have worked extensively with slider ui before so i do know that i can dynamically change the range of the slider but i was thinking more of a continuous sliding experience than a "slightly" disruptive experience.

hope i have made some sense ... i know there are ready made timeline sliders available but they don't have everything i want.. hence this question..

any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I advise against a “scrolling slider”: it is *very* hard to get the additional scrolling right so that it’s not to slow and doesn’t shoot over the top. Instead, what about showing only the left/rightmost option and the current value above/inside the handle? I have done the latter and it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/fFtKx/)?
When you drag a slider years slides too.
HTML:

```
<div id="yearsHolder" style="height: 20px !important; overflow-x: hidden; position: relative;"></div>
<div id="slider" style="width: 200px;"></div>
<div id="amount"></div>
```

Javascript (main is the `slide` event):

```
var yearTextWidth = 50;
var yearsPerText = 5;// every 5 years appears text
$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 1900,
        max: 2000,
        step: 1,
        disabled: false,
        animate: true,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: false,
        value: 1900,
        create: function(event, ui) {
            var slider = $(this);
            var value = slider.slider("value");
            $("#amount").html(value);
            var sliderWidth = slider.width();
            var yearTextsLength = Math.floor(sliderWidth / yearTextWidth);// left or equal
            var yearsHolder = $("#yearsHolder");
            yearsHolder.css("width", (sliderWidth + yearTextWidth) + "px !important");
            var min = $(this).slider("option", "min");
            var max = $(this).slider("option", "max");
            var currentYear = min;
            var yearHolder;
            while (currentYear <= max) {
                yearHolder = $("<div></div>");
                yearHolder.css("text-align", "left");
                yearHolder.css("position", "absolute");
                yearHolder.css("left", (((currentYear - min) / yearsPerText) * yearTextWidth) + "px");
                yearHolder.css("width", yearTextWidth + "px !important");
                yearHolder.html(currentYear);
                yearsHolder.append(yearHolder);
                currentYear += yearsPerText;
            }
        },
        slide: function(event, ui){
            var value = ui.value;
            $("#amount").html(value);
            var slider = $(this);
            var min = slider.slider("option", "min");
            var max = slider.slider("option", "max");
            var width = slider.width();
            $.each($("#yearsHolder div"), function(index, element){
                var div = $(element);
                var currentLeft = parseInt(div.css("left"));
                var currentYear = parseInt(div.html());
                div.css("left", ((value - min) * (width / (max - min)) + ((currentYear - min) - (value - min)) * (yearTextWidth / yearsPerText)) + "px");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**UPD**
You can set `yearsPerText = 1` to show current year near a slider.

Comment: thanks guys will keep it in mind and get back to you once ihave a working prototype...

Comment: Hm... my variat doesn't work? [http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/fFtKx/](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/fFtKx/)